# How to calculate the dispersion relation for a wave equation with non-constant speed of wave propagation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, waves, dispersion

Specifically, it is a one-dimensional wave equation for waves on a string with a non-constant cross-section, i. e. $$S(x)=S_1+S_2 \cos{2x}; \qquad c(x)=\sqrt{F/\rho\, S(x)}.$$ Separating the variables yields the Mathieu differential equation $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+[a-2q\cos (2x) ]y=0,$$ $a$ and $q$ are parameters of the string. One form of the solution is the Floquet solution $$F(a,q,x) = \exp(i \mu \,x) \, P(a,q,x),$$ where $P(a,q,x)$ is a periodic function and $\mu$ is a complex exponent (another form of the solution are the Mathieu sine and cosine, which are odd and even functions respectively, if that is of any use). The temporal part of the solution is sinusoidal. My question is how to get the dispersion relation $\omega(k)$ from the equation.

With the normal wave equation one would plug the straight wave solution $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ into the equation, which would yield the dispersion relation $\omega=c\,k$.

Comment: I can point you to the paper by Rhines that seems related: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1029/RG008i002p00303/asset/rog166.pdf;jsessionid=F2CE29B6A660CEDADF3A361746DD6107.f02t04?v=1&t=hzk7hsya&s=12155965946dfbfa4203e33a1ebe750d8803ff49 If you're behind a wall, let me know and I can try to find some time to reproduce his work.  I'm also confused about your notation. What is S, what is c, what is F?

Comment: I don't have access to the link. S is the cross-section area of the string, c is the speed of wave propagation and F is the string tension.

Comment: You have an expression for $F$ and can relate it to $c(x) = \omega/k$ through your expression for $S(x)$.  Note that $c(x) = \omega/k$ is the general definition of phase speed, assuming that is what you meant by "speed of wave propagation".  So can't you just invert a few things here and do some symbol gymnastics to get the result you seek?